# Get Members of a Group in Azure DevOps Server 2022

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server

I need to know the way to get the users of a specific group through the REST API of Azure DevOps Server 2022, that is, **on-premise**. We are going to use as an example url 192.168.0.1 and the DefaultCollection as practice purposes.
I have searched the documentation but when I try to apply them in my case they don't work for me, I get a 404 Not Found.

For now I am doing:

http://192.168.0.1:8080/tfs/_apis/groupentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.1
http://192.168.0.1:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/groupentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.1

Neither seems to work. They throw 404.

I don't know if it has something to do with it, but I was reading on this [website](https://michaelmaillot.github.io/tips/20210914-azdo-project-admin-members-programmatically/) that a "vsaex" prefix is used for groupentitlements, "vssps" for graph and "status" for status, so I tried the following:
http://vsaex.192.168.0.1:8080/tfs/_apis/groupentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.1
http://vsaex.192.168.0.1:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/groupentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.1

Again, neither seems to work.

Also I tried differents api-versions, or without using any of them. I don't have any trouble using other parts of the REST API, e.g.: I can get Projects of a collection, Teams by Project, etc. and they work fine.

Comment: Hi @Gaspar, does the answer below helps? If it helps, just a remind of [ accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: No, it doesn't because as I said I need to get users of a specific group. That API is "used to determine whether an user has permissions to perform a specific action on a specific resource." Thank you for trying to help but I found your answer kind of generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found that with this call you can GET what I was searching.

```
 - http://{server:port}/tfs/{collection}/_api/_identity/ReadGroupMembers?scope={groupId}&readMembers=true&api-version=6.0
   you can do that.
```

If you need the groupId you can get it from:

```
 - http://{server:port}/tfs/{collection}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue={group
   Name}&api-version=6.0
```

If you have more than 1 group called the same, search in the response the group that you want in providerDisplayName property -> [{ProjectName}]\\{Group Name}
There you will get the groupId and from that you can get the Members of a Group

The weird thing is that you have tu use _api/_identity instead of _apis/identities.

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong APIs. Group Entitlements are for managing licenses for Azure DevOps Services and do not exist in on-prem versions of Azure DevOps Server.

You are looking for the [Security APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0).

Comment: I'm not looking for Security APIs. Let me explain the problem better.
For example. If I need to get the members of a TEAM of a specific project I can do:


http://192.168.0.1:8080/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/teams/{TeamId}/members?api-version=6.0-preview.1


If I need to get the projectId for previus GET I could list all the projects with:
http://192.168.0.1:8080/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0-preview.1

Comment: If I need to get teamId I could list all the teams of a specific project with:
http://192.168.0.1:8080/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/teams?api-version=6.0-preview.1


So after that long example, you can see there is an API for get team members and from what I believe there is not group members API.

Answer (score 0):

I had no success with

```
http://{server:port}/tfs/{collection}/_api/_identity/ReadGroupMembers...
```

So I had to resolve to using

```
http://{server:port}/tfs/{collection}/_api/identies?identityIds...
```

instead.

```
$Server = 'server:port'
$Org = 'tfs'
$REST = "https://$Server/$Org/_apis"
$ProjectName = '[Project Name]\' #If empty, all projects will be included
$GroupName = 'Group Name'

[Array]$Groups = Invoke-RestMethod (
  "$REST/identities?searchFilter=General" +
  "&filterValue=$ProjectName$GroupName" +
  "&queryMemberShip=Direct" +
  "&api-version=5.1"
) |
  select -ExpandProperty Value

$Groups | foreach {#replace identityId with the Identity Objects

  $ThisMemberIdsString = $_.memberIds -join ','

  $_.memberIds = Invoke-RestMethod (
    "$REST/identities?IdentityIds=$ThisMemberIdsString" +
    "&api-version=5.1"
  ) |
    select -ExpandProperty Value

}

$Groups
```

Now, `$Groups.memberIds` will contain the member objects instead of the memberIds.

(This script could of course be written in much fewer lines and with less variables, but I prefer this format for clarity in the example.)